# Hide multiple recipients and display only the receiver email id using mailMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailmessage

I want to send email to multiple recipients , but when the user receives the mail he should see only "his" email id in the "to" field.

Below is the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < recipients.Length; i++)
{
  emailMessage.To.Add(recipients[i]);
  TheSMTPClient.Send(@emailMessage);                    
}
```

Using the above code, all the email id will be listed in "to" field. I guess BCC is not the solution as it has 1 constant id in to field and rest in BCC.

Comment: You'll have to send an email to each recipient separately

Comment: I tried ,  for (int i = 0; i < recipients.Length; i++)
                    {
                        SmtpClient smtp =new SmtpClient();
                        emailMessage.To.Add(recipients[i]);
                        smtp.Send(@emailMessage);
                    }    It did not fire any email.

Comment: does it fire a single email? to a single email address?

Comment: no. It doesnt fire any.

Comment: using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                        {
                            MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage("Notifications@crowncabinc.com", recipients[i],
                                "Notice", msg);
                            smtp.Send(@emailMessage);
                        } tried this. did not work

Comment: Well, start debugging this issue. Multiple emails is not an issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

What about ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < recipients.Length; i++)
{
  emailmessage.To.Clear();
  emailMessage.To.Add(recipients[i]);
  TheSMTPClient.Send(@emailMessage);                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < recipients.Length; i++)
                    {
                            MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage("sendr@gmail.com", recipients[i],
                                "Notice", msg);
                            TheSMTPClient.Send(@emailMessage);
                    }
```